# Cat6 Cable Issue. Driving me Nuts - Help Please

Tags: network-shares, cat6, cat5e

I have a 180’ cat6 connecting main house and guest house.  It’s been working for 6 months no issues.  Two days ago it stopped.  I checked one of the end point and it was loose to I Re-crimped T568B on both ends.  Tester shows OPEN 3&6 pair.  I have Re-crimped several time no luck.

[image]

Any suggestions

Comment: could be a cable issue - there's 180`'` of cable between the two ends

Comment: check another cable with the tester

Comment: Eliminate the tester as the problem, outside of that, your likely going to have to replace the cable

Comment: it could be broken somewhere inbetween - 'better' tools sometimes tell you *where* but just replacing the cable is likely cheaper

Answer (score 3):

- Check continuity directly on the wires - if it's gone there's nothing you can do with crimping.
- If 100 Mbit/s is sufficient you can rearrange the pairs to replace 3-6 by e.g. 7-8. Do make sure you swap full pairs, not single wires.
- If the cable is directly buried and needs replacement you should use a proper tube. Simple plenum or even patch cable doesn't last long in the earth. Cable for direct burial also exists (thx @Spiff) but a conduit makes replacing/upgrading the cable so much easier.

Comment: FYI Cat 6 cable designed for direct burial exists. Tough weatherproof and cut/abrasion-resistant jacket, waterproof gel filling. If you buy direct burial cable, you can directly bury it without a conduit.